# Download directory from sftp

Tags: linux, sftp, lftp

I want to download directory from sftp to  a server.I am able to login to sftp using

```
  sftp rob2056@storagename
```

and then can get individual files using :

```
   get *.txt /remotedir
```

But I want to download multiple directories from sftp to remote,which I am not able to do:

```
    get -r * /remotedir
```

(does not work)

Comment: Does not work in what sense? Any error message(s)?

Comment: it says invalid flag

Comment: Try `get -r /remotedir` instead?

Comment: Thats what it says invalid flag,again

Comment: Mm. Try with `sftp -r rob2056@storagename` ... ? I'm starting to suspect your version of `sftp` may not support `-r`. In which case you would update it or use another tool like `scp`.

Comment: from where i should use scp? logged in remote server ?

Comment: From your workstation; some examples: https://kb.iu.edu/d/agye

Comment: Which SFTP client do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mirror -c TestTransfer/ /remotedir
```

This command can be used to copy the whole directory.

Comment: Which SFTP client do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Is the local directory remote already created before issuing the command 
`get -r * /remotedir` ?

I tried this:

- Created a directory on the local machine **remotedir** inside which I had to transfer all the folders.
- Issued the command `get -r * remotedir` without the slash and it worked. I've no idea why the **/** matters though.

Answer (score 0):

Use **mget** instead of **get** when using metacharacters like `'` and `?`.  You might think of the *m* as meaning *multiple*.

Comment: mget is for multiple files when i am in a directory.I want to download multiple directories.So it does not work in this case.its basically same as get *

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your SFTP client does not know how to mirror directories.

Though there are other SFTP clients. You might want to install a different one or a newer version of your client. The SFTP client in the RedHat package `openssh-clients-6.4`, for example, knows the -r option.

This is how I got the version of my SFTP  client:

```
rpm -qf /usr/bin/sftp
```

Apart from that, you might want to do a web search for `sftp client`.